# Initialization hook for Clojure Noir WAR/Servlet (CloudFoundry)

Tags: java, clojure, war, leiningen

I'm building a Clojure Noir web application to run as a WAR file in CloudFoundry.

In my project.clj I have:

```
:ring {:handler appname.server/handler}
```

In server.clj I create a handler using Noir:

```
(def handler (noir.server/gen-handler {:ns 'appname}))
```

I build the WAR file using a lein ring plugin:

```
lein ring uberwar
```

Then push to CloudFoundry using:

```
vmc push appname
```

The request handler works fine and I can browse to the URL of the application just fine.

**So the question is: what is the correct way to do initialization when the application is started?**

I can do the following in server.clj:

```
(when (System/getenv "VCAP_APPLICATION")
  (init-func))
```

But there are a couple problems with that. First, it seems like that is doing the initialization at the wrong time (when the code is read/eval'd rather than on app start). Second, the protector is specific to CloudFoundry and I certain there is a proper general WAR way to do this.

I think this is the purpose of the contextInitialized method on the ServletContextListener but how do I hook that in with Noir/ring?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out by looking at [ring source for WAR handling](https://github.com/weavejester/lein-ring/blob/master/src/leiningen/ring/war.clj)

The project.clj :ring map takes an :init keyword like so:

```
:ring {:init appname.server/my-init
       :handler appname.server/handler}
```

The my-init function will be called on application startup.

**Caveat**: this apparently balloons the amount of memory needed by the application for initial startup. 128M was sufficient without the initialization. With the initialization code , the app startup failed, so I had to bump the memory to 256M. I suspect that with the init code the JVM doesn't have time to garbage collect before the Clojure code is compiled/executed.